# スレッドIDの取得方法が知りたい

Tags: c#, マルチスレッド

VisualStudio2008でデバッグ実行時にコンソールに表示されるスレッドIDの取得方法が知りたいです。
以下のようにコンソールに出力されますが、終了したスレッドが何スレッドなのかの判断がつきません。
`スレッド 0x43d8 はコード 0 (0x0) で終了しました。`

Comment: この辺の記事を参考に。[C# でスレッド ID を取得する](https://takachan.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/03/11/165553), [ManagedThreadIdのスレッドＩＤについて](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/5895835e-2dd7-431c-8932-53a2ecac3fd6/managedthreadid12398124731252412483124896532165316123951238812356123?forum=netfxgeneralja), [スレッドからスレッドIDを取得する](https://codeday.me/jp/qa/20181130/15398.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

デバッガーであれば[スレッドウィンドウ](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/debugger/walkthrough-debugging-a-multithreaded-application?view=vs-2019)に情報がまとめられています。

プログラムからはネイティブのスレッドIDは意識するべきではありません。.NETの`Thread`と１：１対応するとは保証されていないからです。[Thread.Nameプロパティ](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.name?view=netframework-4.8)で`Thread`に名前を付けられるので、これで管理するべきです。

なお、Visual Studio 2008はすでにサポート終了済みですので、適切なバージョンに移行するべきです。開発環境と作成されるプログラムの実行環境は別です。古い開発環境を維持する意味はないでしょう。

Comment: Thread.nameプロパティを使用しようと思います。ありがとうございます。